# Anaconda - Not updating

Tags: python, anaconda, bokeh

I am using Anaconda installation and many times the updates don't work.

For example, some bokeh commands work well when I run the a python program from the command line (i.e c:> python testPlot.py), but will not work in the IPython console or from Spyder.

I tried updating conda, Anaconda, bokeh, but the behavior doesn't change. This is not just this one package. Others have the same issue.

Any idea?

Thanks.

C:>conda update conda
conda                     4.0.6                    py27_0

C:>conda update anaconda
anaconda                  4.0.0               np110py27_0

C:>conda update bokeh
bokeh                     0.11.1                   py27_0

Comment: Unless you share some code that you are having problems with, it is impossible to say anything specific or offer any suggestions.

Comment: [link] (http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/legend.html). This example shows an error "ImportError: cannot import name vplot" when I am using spyder (IPython or Python console). But when I use it from the DOS command line "python myBokeh.py" it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a cmd prompt in Windows or Terminal on a mac and paste this with the version you are having trouble installing.

```
conda install anaconda-navigator=(whatever version is giving you trouble)
```